# Get data of a selected row in listview

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

I have created an application in which the listview gets populated from the database.Now i want to see in a toast the details of the **value of a row which is clicked**. How can I get the data of the clicked row??

Below is my .java page..

```
public class ListviewActivity extends ListActivity{

ListView mListView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listlayout);
    mListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

     DbAdapter dbHelper = new DbAdapter(this);
        dbHelper.open();

        // Get a Cursor for the list items
        Cursor listCursor = dbHelper.fetchListItems();
        startManagingCursor(listCursor);

        // set the custom list adapter
        setListAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this, listCursor));

        mListView = getListView();
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id){
                String val=(String)(mListView.getItemAtPosition(position));

                Toast.makeText(ListviewActivity.this,position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


}
```

When i click on a row the application gets forcibly closed with the following errors:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13011): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(13011): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor
E/AndroidRuntime(13011):    at com.android.pickuplistview.ListviewActivity$1.onItemClick(ListviewActivity.java:38)
E/AndroidRuntime(13011):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
E/AndroidRuntime(13011):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
E/AndroidRuntime(13011):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
E/AndroidRuntime(13011):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(13011):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(13011):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(13011):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(13011):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13011):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(13011):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(13011):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(13011):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My DB Adapter page is given here:

```
public class DbAdapter {
 private static final String DB_NAME = "ListData";
    private static final String TABLE_ITEMS = "itemslist";
    public static final String COL_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COL_ITEMS = "items";
    public static final String COL_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COL_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String COL_STATUS="status";

    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private final Context mCtx;
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String CREATE_DB_TABLE_DATES = 

        "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_ITEMS+" ("+ 
            COL_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+ 
            COL_ITEMS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            COL_NAME + " TEXT, " + 
            COL_ADDRESS + " TEXT, " +
            COL_STATUS + " TEXT " +
            ");";

    private static final String CREATE_TEST_DATA1 = 
        "INSERT INTO "+TABLE_ITEMS+
            " ("+
                COL_ITEMS+","+
                COL_NAME+","+
                COL_ADDRESS+","+
                COL_STATUS+
                ") VALUES (" +
                "'Gems',"+
                "'KAJU',"+
                "'Behala',"+
                "'DELIVERED'"+
                ");";

    private static final String CREATE_TEST_DATA2 = 
        "INSERT INTO "+TABLE_ITEMS+
        " ("+
        COL_ITEMS+","+
        COL_NAME+","+
        COL_ADDRESS+","+
        COL_STATUS+
        ") VALUES (" +
        "'Eclairs',"+
        "'BIJU',"+
        "'Joka',"+
        "'PENDING'"+
            ");";

    private static final String CREATE_TEST_DATA3 = 
        "INSERT INTO "+TABLE_ITEMS+
        " ("+
        COL_ITEMS+","+
        COL_NAME+","+
        COL_ADDRESS+","+
        COL_STATUS+
        ") VALUES (" +
        "'Donut',"+
        "'RAJU',"+
        "'Kasba',"+
        "'DELIVERED'"+
            ");";

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_DB_TABLE_DATES);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TEST_DATA1);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TEST_DATA2);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TEST_DATA3);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            // if the new version is higher than the old version, 
            // delete existing tables:
            if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ITEMS);
                onCreate(db);
            } else {
                // otherwise, create the database
                onCreate(db);
            }

        }

    }

    /**
     * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
     * opened/created
     * 
     * @param ctx the Context within which to work
     */
    public DbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public DbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public Cursor fetchListItems() {

        Cursor cursor = 
            mDb.query(TABLE_ITEMS, new String[] 
                      {COL_ID, COL_ITEMS, COL_NAME, COL_ADDRESS, COL_STATUS}, 
                      null, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to cast a Cursor to a String:

```
String val=(String)(mListView.getItemAtPosition(position));
```

At least that's what this error makes it out to be:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor
```

Try getting a String representation of the data from the Cursor, not casting the Cursor to a String directly.

EDIT:

A Cursor contains pointers to information stored in a database. Without knowing how your DB is structured, it'd be impossible for me to really do that for you. However, you can try this format:

```
String val = mListView.getItemAtPosition(position).getString(columnIndexInteger);
```

Where columnIndexInteger is the integer value of the column. If you don't know it, but have a String name for it, you can get it with: getColumnIndex(). If that's the case, adjust this:

```
Cursor c = (Cursor)mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
String val = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbAdapter.COL_NAME));
```

The above line should set val to the database record associated with COL_NAME

Comment: How to do that?? please give me exmaple or it would be better if you edit my code.I'm very ameteur in android.Looking forward for your help.Please..

Comment: i have attached my DB page...kindly check it please

Comment: I edited it. The bottom line should set val to the database record associated with COL_NAME

Comment: when i'm trying to edit as suggested by you a red error line is coming under "getColumnIndex" which says 'The method getColumnIndex(String) is undefined for the type Object'

Comment: I would like to say something off d topic...I have seen your profile and its just amazing.Keep it up.Its highly appreciable what you are doing at this age.kudos kudos..

Comment: Thanks, I updated the bottom line with a more readable version. Cursor has a method getColumnIndex(String) which returns the 0-based index of the row inside the Cursor that is defined by the String you pass in. Try using the two lines above

Comment: a new error mark under the line       mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);                                                         "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Cursor"

Comment: now if i add cast to Cursor then it is showing the ineteger values of the array position such as 0 for row 1,1 for row 2,etc..

Comment: Just cast the object returned by getItemAtPosition to type Cursor (see above), since that's the Object type you're passing as an argument for your ListView's dataset

Comment: Strange, the getString() method should pull the String value in the database associated with the integer returned by getColumnIndex()

Comment: :( :( what should I do now?? need help

Comment: Nvmd, you can't yet. Ok, first, I think you need to pass the ListView an ArrayList of some object, instead of the Cursor, since that's not an array of items. When you call your DB and get the Cursor, loop through all the entries and populate an Object with it's values, then add that to your ArrayList, which you will then pass to the ListView. Then you'll be able to just call the variables directly from the Object at position, and not have to worry about the Cursor except when pulling the data. Also make sure the values in your DB are what you think they are

Comment: @Cruceo...tell me one thing.If I want to pass the row id from the activity page and in another page i catch that row id and form that id i want to get all the data of that row then what will i have to do?? any suggestions???

Comment: You'd have to compare that row id to the position in your dataset. IE. If position is 3, you'd have to get data[position]

Answer (score 0):

This exception occured because you are passing integer value to the toast massage.Toast need char sequence.So replate your line

```
    Toast.makeText(ListviewActivity.this,position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

with

```
  Toast.makeText(ListviewActivity.this,position+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

on click of listView.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help...but the same problem persists :(

Comment: but it sgould not come after replacing this line as I checked it on my end

Comment: have i done any mistake in this line     'String val=(String)(mListView.getItemAtPosition(position)); '